# Matrix rotate to degrees

Tags: c#, matrix, 3d, 2d, rotational-matrices

For a screen overlay I am making for a 3-dimensional game, I need to display icons over certain locations in the 3D world. I've managed to get several variables from the game that should make this possible:

- Player position (x,y,z)
- Camera position (x,y,z)
- Point position (x,y,z)
- Camera Angle(FOV)

Using these variables I managed to get the right and left edge of the camera view. Using these 2 variables I am able to get the point between 0 and 1 where the icon should be displayed on the x axis. (0 is on the left edge, 1 is right edge) This seems to work quite well, but only if I am aligned to either the X or Z axis, as shown in the following example:

[image]

I've been trying to fix this using the following rotation matrix:

```
[ Math.Cos(angle), -Math.Sin(angle) ]
[ Math.Sin(angle), Math.Cos(angle) ]
```

What I do is, I put the player position, camera position and the camera edge positions in the matrix with as rotation point the world point. The problem is, as soon as I put the angle amount at 90 degrees, the X and Y are being flipped. I've been trying to find a solution for this for a few days now, but I can't find it, so I hope anyone can push me in the right direction here. Below are a few parts of my code that might help in finding the solution:

```
float PCDistXZ = (float)Math.Sqrt(deltaPCx * deltaPCx + deltaPCz * deltaPCz); // X/Z distance from the world point to the camera

Point fakeAvatarPos = RotateAround(new Point((int)point.x, (int)point.z), new Point((int)avatar.x, (int)avatar.z), (int)90);
Point fakeCameraPos = RotateAround(new Point((int)point.x, (int)point.z), new Point((int)camera.x, (int)camera.z), (int)90);

double edgeRight = fakeC.X + (Math.Sin(45) * PCDistXZ);
double edgeLeft = fakeC.X - (Math.Sin(45) * PCDistXZ);

float edgeTest_ScreenPositionX = (1 - (float)((edgeRight - P.x) / (edgeRight - edgeLeft))) * screenWidth;

public static Point RotateAround(Point pCenter,Point pPoint, float pAngle)
    {
        double angle = (pAngle * Math.PI) / 180;
        double[,] matrix = new Double[2, 2] {
            { Math.Cos(angle), Math.Sin(angle) }, 
            { Math.Sin(angle), Math.Cos(angle) } 
        };

        double xOffset = pPoint.X - pCenter.X;
        double yOffset = pPoint.Y - pCenter.Y;

        Point newPoint = new Point(
            (int)(((pPoint.X - xOffset) * matrix[0, 0]) - ((pPoint.Y - xOffset) * matrix[0, 1])),
            (int)(((pPoint.X - yOffset) * matrix[1, 0]) + ((pPoint.Y - yOffset) * matrix[1, 1]))
        );

        newPoint.X += (int)xOffset;
        newPoint.Y += (int)yOffset;
        return new Point(newPoint.X,newPoint.Y);
    }
```

Note: I've changed the names of some of the variables to more understandable one, so it could be possible that there are inconsistencies in the names.

EDIT: I found out about view- and projection matrices. I might be able to use those to convert the 3D position to screen. I'm not sure if it's possible to make this matrices with the limited information I have though.

Comment: Shouldn't you compute the *normal* of an icon's quad so that it points towards you ?

Comment: The icon always points towards it, I think I forgot to mention the game I'm making the overlay for is not mine, which means I don't have access to the direct World-To-Screen point, which in this case I'm trying to find